# Android - Unable to call methods defined in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to call a method that I've created in my ViewModel class but I'm not able to access it in my MainActivity where I've initialized my ViewModel.

This is my ViewModel class

```
public class MovieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private MovieRepository movieRepository;
public List<Movie> movieList;

public MovieViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    movieRepository = new MovieRepository();
}

public List<Movie> getMovieList(String sortChoice, int pageNumber) {
    movieList = movieRepository.getMovieList(sortChoice,pageNumber);
    return movieList;
}
}
```

This is part of MainActivity

```
    private ViewModel mViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        pageNumber = 1;
        sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String defaultSort = MovieConstants.POPULAR;
        choiceOfSorting = sharedPref.getString(PREF_SORT_KEY, defaultSort);

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
`
```

When I try calling the method getMovieList with the line

```
mViewModel.getMovieList(someVariable, someVariable);
```

it shows in red saying - Cannot resolve symbol 'getMovieList'

Comment: you are saving viewmodel in `ViewModel` instance, use `MovieViewModel` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private ViewModel mViewModel;`

ViewModel doesn't have getMovieList, so change that to

`private MovieViewModel viewModel;`

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);` to a variable of the base type `ViewModel`, so you will only be able to access methods available in `ViewModel`.

Replace `private ViewModel mViewModel;` with `private MovieViewModel mViewModel;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `mViewModel` is of type `ViewModel`, which has no method called `getMovieList`. Change the type to `MovieViewModel`.